# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting an error and it will not compile Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
const fbConfig = {};

const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: "users",
  useFirestoreForProfile: true
};

// Initialize firebase instance
firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  firebase: firebaseReducer,
  firestore: firestoreReducer
});

// Create store with reducers and initial state
const initialState = {};
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rrfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>HOMR</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <App />
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: still gives the same error with the changes :(

Comment: It compiles but still gives the same error on the page

Comment: show the import statments